# background-image doesn't render image

Tags: html, css

I was trying to set my page a background image and yet it didn't seem to work the way I expected it to. Here's the code:

```
body 
{
    background-image: url("sf.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Kozuka Gothic Pro", Avenir, sans-serif;
}
```

I was wondering what went wrong here. Thanks in advance. Note: the image was in the same folder as the file i'm running.

Comment: Have you used developer tools to make sure the image is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/swynw/31/)

Just a small change in your code.

```
body {
        background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUYP4.jpg?s=128&g=1");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        font-family: "Kozuka Gothic Pro", Avenir, sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: but why mine doesn't work at all. I know it's kind of silly cuz i've been doing this for a while now and the images work fine except for this one.

Comment: its really weird... i tried on IE and Chrome works fine for me.

Comment: i even compared this code with my other chunk of code that worked but i found no difference. It's so weird.

Comment: @Jatin-> If the permissions of your image is not correct then the image may not show up. Just change the permission to `777` and try again. Hope it helps.

Comment: You're right @AnupamBasak it's all about the permission, now it worked thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Coz background size cannot be 100 it can be cover or contain, and use background instead of background-image  and all,  use a background-size:cover it will work

body {

background : url (ur image path);

background-size:cover;

width:100%;

//and other necessary code
}

Comment: Give it a width too 100 % and remove that no repeat coz u want it to cover entire page right

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have double tab indent bring it all back on tab.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permission of the image to 777 and the image will show up correctly.